# How to populate a Chapel class object from a JSON?

Tags: json, chapel

In Python, I can create objects from JSON pretty easily.  I can either populate classes or just create a generic object.  I see that Chapel has a `read` method for JSON, but I'm not sure how to use it.

If I have:

```
class Fighter {
  var subclass:string;
  var level:int;
}
```

and a string:

```
s = "{'subclass':'Ninja', 'level':7}"
```

How do I get a `Fighter` object?
And are there methods like:

```
n = json.loads(s)
n['subclass']             # = 'ninja', but just as a field key
```

Or:

```
Hattori = Fighter.read(s);
Hattori['subclass']       # = 'ninja'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be possible to make something like `json.loads(s)` work by creating some particular type (e.g. JSONNode) and populating it.

However right now we can get something in your example to work:

```
 class Fighter {
  var subclass:string;
  var level:int;
}

var mem = openmem();
var writer = mem.writer().write('{"subclass":"ninja", "level":7}');
var reader = mem.reader();

var f = new Fighter();
reader.readf("%jt", f);

writeln(f);
```

Note that the class instance currently has to be allocated before you read it. Or you can use a record, for which there isn't a `nil` value.

Comment: @mppf would a `from pych.extern import FromC` + **`@FromC`-decorated c-code** body unlock any such features in need to Brian, straight integrated into / call-able from python environment?